# How to detect with javascript that mobile device screen is closed

Tags: javascript, mobile, screen, progressive-web-apps

Is it possible to detect is mobile phone screen is closed (or any screen) or if browser windows is shrinked(in desktop brwoser)? I'd like to know if mobile user has closed phone screen in my PWA application. Same thing if user is using another mobile application but screen is on (My application is working background and music is playing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to detect is mobile phone screen is closed (or any
>   screen)

Yes. If I've understood your question correctly, this will also work for your third case where a user has your app on in the background:

`isClosed = window.closed;`

**isClosed** will return a boolean

- true if the window has been closed
- false if the window is open

For further reference, check the documentation [here](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/closed).

> or if browser windows is shrinked(in desktop brwoser)?

Yes. You will need the Page Visibility API. Its documentation is [here](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Page_Visibility_API).